# Misused header name. ... response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects

Tags: http, azure-functions

I'm working with an API with a web hook. i need to send back a 401 to trigger the proper logic. But my code is giving the error:

```
 Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.
```

This is my code to send a 401 response:

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
 response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(),327);
 response.Content.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"myCloud\"" );
 response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
 return response;
```

What is the issue with the headers? The error implies that the headers are not intended for a HTTP Response, but a Request. But I don't get it since this is how the other API is designed to work -- it expects a 401 RESPONSE with the www-authenticate header.

This is being returned from an Azure HTTP triggered Function (over HTTPS) (if that makes any difference). I'm trying to understand if I can ignore the error or if I am breaking some HTTP rules here?.

Comment: Are you sending content in the response? If no, why do you send Content-Type?

Comment: Yes, per the code sample, it is an HttpResponseMessage. I set content-type because the sample from the API says to specify the Content-Type, but removing that/adding that has not affect. the one header causing the problem is the www-authenticate. with that added in, the error message is produced.

Comment: ...but when the response is indeed empty, setting Content-Type does not make any sense. Anyway; my suspicion is that the framework special-cases authentication.